# Getting a char* from a _variant_t in optimal time

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, ole, bstr

Here's the code I want to speed up.   It's getting a value from an ADO recordset and converting it to a char*.   But this is slow.    Can I skip the creation of the _bstr_t?

```
                _variant_t var = pRs->Fields->GetItem(i)->GetValue();

                if (V_VT(&var) == VT_BSTR)
                {
                    char* p = (const char*) (_bstr_t) var;
```

Comment: I would recommend doing some timings with the methods proposed here for confirmation. Use QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency API's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 4 bytes of the BSTR contain the length. You can loop through and get every other character if unicode or every character if multibyte. Some sort of memcpy or other method would work too. IIRC, this can be faster than `W2A` or casting `(LPCSTR)(_bstr_t)`

Comment: This is a crazy suggestion. What happens if the BSTR contains wide characters? You'll just corrupt the data.

Comment: If you know for sure what your dataset is, then no issue. You sacrifice flexibility for speed.

Comment: Agree with PiNoYBoY82, it's a hack, but it works when planets align in a certain way.

Comment: The characters are ansi.  For me, this hack works, is safe, and it's very fast.

Comment: You are storing ANSI chars in a BSTR? Urgh. 

On Win32, BSTRs are always wide char -- everything else is a dirty hack.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem (other than the possibility of a memory copy inside _bstr_t) is that you're converting the UNICODE BSTR into an ANSI char*.

You can use the USES_CONVERSION macros which perform the conversion on the stack, so they might be faster. Alternatively, keep the BSTR value as unicode if possible.

to convert:

```
USES_CONVERSION;
char* p = strdup(OLE2A(var.bstrVal));

// ...

free(p);
```

remember - the string returned from OLE2A (and its sister macros) return a string that is allocated on the stack - return from the enclosing scope and you have garbage string unless you copy it (and free it eventually, obviously)

Answer (score 2):

This creates a temporary on the stack:

```
USES_CONVERSION;
char *p=W2A(var.bstrVal);
```

This uses a slightly newer syntax and is probably more robust. It has a configurable size, beyond which it will use the heap so it avoids putting massive strings onto the stack:

```
char *p=CW2AEX<>(var.bstrVal);
```

Comment: Well, I liked this approach in theory, except it's not really faster according to my timings.

Comment: I'm surprised it isn't. Your original method requires the creation of an extra BSTR which has to go through the COM allocator. Both of mine just copy into a buffer onto the stack with conversion. If your original string is long enough, the overhead from the conversion is probably most significant

Comment: My strings are short, but I have, oh, 150,000 thousand of them or so in a loop.   That is I'm looping thru the rows and columns of an ADO recordset, converting the BSTRs to char*s, then pushing the char*s into an std::vector of std::strings.    Takes about 3.2 seconds both ways.

Comment: Well you still have to perform the conversion from unicode. Have you considered trying to avoid the conversion? Change your whole app to use unicode? Are you sure you have the right bottleneck? maybe it is the Getvalue() methods?

Comment: 1800 INFORMATION, thanks for the suggestions.   There are other parts of my loop that contribute to the 3.2 seconds, but in this Stackoverflow question, I was focusing on just this narrow point.

I'm not free to do things over, but I think going with unicode from end-to-end would have been better.

Comment: Allocating memory on the heap with alloca(n) is not slow. In fact it can be optimized down to three instructions: SUB ESP, n; MOV EAX, ESP; RET 4;

Comment: alloca does not allocate memory on the heap

Answer (score 0):

```
_variant_t var = pRs->Fields->GetItem(i)->GetValue();
```

You can also make this assignment quicker by avoiding the fields collection all together.  You should only use the Fields collection when you need to retrieve the item by name.  If you know the fields by index you can instead use this.

```
_variant_t vara = pRs->Collect[i]->Value;
```

Note i cannot be an integer as ADO does not support VT_INTEGER, so you might as well use a long variable.

Comment: OP is asking for a `char*` from `_variant_t`. Your answer returns a `_variant_t` from `recordset`. your answer has nothing to do with question

Answer (score -2):

Ok, my C++ is getting a little rusty... but I don't think the conversion is your problem.  That conversion doesn't really do anything except tell the compiler to consider _bstr_t a char*.  Then you're just assigning the address of that pointer to p.  Nothing's actually being "done."

Are you sure it's not just slow getting stuff from GetValue?

Or is my C++ rustier than I think...

Comment: Actually there is a bunch of magic going on behind the scenes by the _bstr_t class to convert the string from unicode to ANSI

Comment: That depends. I don't know the details of the _variant_t class, but if it defines an operator _bstr_t() then that's the function that will be called if a _variant_t to _bstr_t conversion is needed.

Comment: Those aren't mere casts for the compiler.   I know that from stepping through the code.   Objects are being constructed.